# How to delay KeyPress function when user is typing, so it doesn't fire a request for each keystroke?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**background**

I have a number of dropdowns on a page. If you change the first one, the rest of the dropdowns are updated according to what you've selected.

In our case, we deal with fund data. So the first dropdown is "All Fund Types". You select "Hedge Funds", and the next dropdown is filtered by options that only apply to Hedge Funds.

The client is now asking me to put a text field into the mix, which when the user starts typing, will effect those results.

So if they type "USD", the second dropdown will only contain options that have funds with "USD" in the name.

**problem**

The specific problem that I'm having is that with the code I'm using:

```
$('#Search').keypress(function () {
    // trigger the updating process
});
```

It's triggering the search for each key press. So when I type "USD" I'm getting 3 requests immediately - one for "U", one for "US" and one for "USD".

I've tried setting a timeout with this:

```
$('#Search').keypress(function () { 
    // I figure 2 seconds is enough to type something meaningful
    setTimeout(getFilteredResultCount(), 2000);
});
```

but all that does is wait 2 seconds before doing what I've described.

I'm sure this problem has been solved before. Could somebody suggest how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass the return value of `getFilteredResultCount` to `setTimeout` and not the function itself?

Comment: What you want is called *event debouncing*. [There are plugins for jQuery](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)

Comment: This looks very interesting, but at this hour on a Friday & that much text - it's going to wait until Monday!! :-)

good point about the return value of `getFilteredResultCount`. Luckily I don't need it to return anything,  but it's good to keep in mind

Comment: So you probably want `setTimeout(getFilteredResultCount, 2000);`. If you add parenthesis, you are calling the function immediately.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The way I have done this before is to set a timeout, but clear the existing timeout each time a new key is pressed. That way you should only get the request being sent when the user has *stopped* typing.

```
var timeoutId = 0;
$('#Search').keypress(function () { 
    clearTimeout(timeoutId); // doesn't matter if it's 0
    timeoutId = setTimeout(getFilteredResultCount, 500);
    // Note: when passing a function to setTimeout, just pass the function name.
    // If you call the function, like: getFilteredResultCount(), it will execute immediately.
});
```

(I'd go for about 500ms timeout.)

Comment: +1 for beating me to it. Was just about to suggest OP clear his `setTimeout` on new event.

Comment: I tried this out, and it's doing exactly the same as my original problem.. I'm still submitting 3 requests for U, S & D. I'll have a closer look and see if I can do something

Comment: Obviously if you leave more than 500ms between each keypress, you'll get three requests. But you know that, right?

Comment: I understand what you're saying about exceeding the timeout value. I'm not doing that though. I'm typing USD all within .5 seconds - I've even increased the timeout to 1000. It's still firing off 3 requests though. The first one for 'U' and the second 2 for 'USD'. -- also, just to clarify I've changed keypress() to keyup()

Comment: Odd. Is your timeoutId variable in a global scope? I.e. it wouldn't work if I moved its declaration to within the callback. That's all I can think of. I've used this solution a few times now and it definitely works.

Comment: I think it was a problem with the code.. i checked Firefox's error console and it was saying that the first parameter to setTimeout needed to be in quotes.. as such, I think what you've supplied is otherwise correct! Thanks

Comment: @Dave: The problem here is that `setTimeout(getFilteredResultCount(), 500);` executes the function immediately. Don't pass a string, just pass the function itself: `setTimeout(getFilteredResultCount, 500);` (without `()`) (I know I said the same above, but I wanted @Tim to know too).

Comment: Felix & Tim you are both awesome. This solved all my problems!

Comment: What do you do if you need to pass a parameter to `getFilteredResultCount`? Will it still execute immediately?

Comment: FYI, if you need to pass a parameter, you can wrap your function call in another function, like so: `setTimeout( function() { getFilteredResultCount(someParameterOfMine) }, 500);`