# How to smooth a jQuery script that takes time to execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, delayed-execution

I have a jQuery script that searches in the DOM and shows the results in a list.

There is a simplified version of the script here: http://jsfiddle.net/FuJta/1/

There is usually a large number of results, so the script can take a while to execute. (In the example above, this is simulated with a function that delays the script). So if you type too fast in the searchbox, the script prevents you from typing, and it feels bad.

How could I change my script so that you can type freely, and the results show up when they are ready. I want something like the facebook search : if you type too fast, the results are just delayed, but you can still type.

**Html**

```
<p>Type in foo, bar or baz for searching. It works, but it is quite slow.</p><br/>
<input type="text" id="search"/>

<div id="container" style="display:none">
    <div class="element">foo</div>
    <div class="element">bar</div>
    <div class="element">baz</div>
</div>


<div id="results">
</div>​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    function refreshResults() {
        var search = $('#search').val();
        var $filtered = $('#container .element').clone().filter(function() {
            var info = $(this).text();
            return info.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
        });
        $('#results').empty();
        $filtered.each(function() {
            $('#results').append($(this));
        });
    }

    // simulating script delay
    function pausecomp(millis) {
        var date = new Date();
        var curDate = null;
        do {
            curDate = new Date();
        }
        while (curDate - date < millis);
    }

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        pausecomp(700);
        refreshResults();
    });
});​
```

One solution could to refresh the results only when pressing enter. This way, the delay for searching the results feels ok. But I would prefer if I just delay the results and let the user freely type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913181/how-to-delay-keypress-function-when-user-is-typing-so-it-doesnt-fire-a-request

Comment: Ah, there is the answer I was about to post ;) sigh .. those duplicates .. :D

Comment: Why don't you check out how the autocomplete function works, i think you are trying to create the same results here. May be that will help.

Comment: It's not really a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913181/how-to-delay-keypress-function-when-user-is-typing-so-it-doesnt-fire-a-request), but I am ok with closing this as a duplicate as it is very close...

Comment: hmmmmm... I am curious as to why you tagged this with "settimeout" when you didn't use this function in your question? It's almost like you already knew the answer you were going to post before you even asked the question

Comment: @musefan I was suspecting that it could be used in the solution, but I wasn't sure at all (I am not very comfortable with javascript).

Answer (score 2):

You should perform a search like this using asynchronous techniques. No doubt Facebook uses some sort of AJAX to request search results - which means getting the results from the server. This will help prevent the UI 'freeze' that you are currently experiencing.

Here is a very simple example of what you can try (it uses JQuery for the AJAX requests):

```
var searchInProgress = false;//used to work out if a search is in progress
var searchInQueue = false;//used to flag if the input data has changed

function getSearchResults(searchText){
    if (searchInProgress ) {
        searchInQueue = true;
        return;
    }

    searchInProgress = true;
    searchInQueue = false;

   $.getJSON("URL",//URL to handle AJAX query
      { searchText: searchText},//URL parameters can go here
      function (data) {
         //handle your returned data here

         searchInProgress = false;

         if (searchInQueue){//text has changed, so search again
            getSearchResults();
         }
      });
}

$('#search').keyup(function() {
        getSearchResults($(this).val());
});
```

A few things to note: It is probably a good idea to handle failed AJAX requests to ensure you can reset the `searchInProgress` flag as needed. Also, you can add delays after the `keyup` as  desired, but this all depends on how you want it too work.

Answer (score 1):

From [How to delay KeyPress function when user is typing, so it doesn't fire a request for each keystroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913181/how-to-delay-keypress-function-when-user-is-typing-so-it-doesnt-fire-a-request) :

```
var timeoutId = 0;
$('#search').keyup(function () { 
    clearTimeout(timeoutId); // doesn't matter if it's 0
    timeoutId = setTimeout(refreshResults, 100);
});
```

It does what I want indeed.

Comment: Though it may still block the UI if the search takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/AbRPn/3/) that divides the search process into steps, returning flow to the browser during the process to allow the UI to respond.

```
$(function() {

    function searchFunc($element,search) {
        var info = $element.text();
        return info.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    }

    var searchProcessor = null;
    function restartSearch() {
        console.log('Restarting...');

        // Clear previous
        if (searchProcessor != null) {
            clearInterval(searchProcessor);
        }
        $('#results').empty();

        // Values for the processor
        var search = $('#search').val();
        var elements = $('#container .element').get();
        console.log('l:',elements,elements.length);

        // Start processing
        searchProcessor = setInterval(function() {
            if (elements.length == 0) {
                // Finished searching all elements
                clearInterval(searchProcessor);
                searchProcessor = null; 
                console.log('Finished.'); 

            } else { 
                console.log('Checking element...'); 
                var $checkElement = $(elements.shift());
                if (searchFunc($checkElement, search)) {
                    $('#results').append($checkElement.clone());
                }
            }
        }, 10);
    }

    $('#search').keyup(function() {
         restartSearch() 
    });
});
```

It only processes one element each time. That should probably be increased so it handles perhaps 10 or 100 each time around, but the important point is that the work is divided into chunks.

This solution should also be faster than the original because it doesn't `clone()` everything, only the elements that were matched.